# Can puzzles come without hints?

Tags: discussion, hints

Can you post a puzzle without any hints so that the people find the answer without any help but using their logic only?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Puzzling.SE! I'm afraid that your question may be considered too broad and primarily opinion-based. Why don't you try to be a bit more concrete, like specifying what type of puzzles are your referring to?

Comment: @dmg is right, you have to add more details in your question to be not-broad. Also, I would suggest to discuss about hints and other questions in Meta.Puzzling, not here in Puzzling.

Comment: @leoll2 I second that. If this is asking about puzzles in general, it's OK here. If it's about what the community wants posted on Puzzling, it belongs in Meta.

Comment: @EngineerToast Ah, you've read the question *that* way. For me, it was a question on "puzzles in general" and hence valid on the main site, but I can see that one can as well read the question as "what should I do if ..." in which case it belongs to the MetaSite... I think this proofs the point DMG has made: The question is not well enough phrased....

Answer (score 5):

### Yes.

Purely logical puzzles (which have the [logical-deduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction) tag) can often be solved without any hints, see for instance [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16918/which-lorry-is-carrying-drugs) and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12995/five-coloured-doors-which-leads-to-freedom).

"Who am I?" riddles (which have the [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) tag) may also be solvable without any hints, see for instance [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5002/name-that-entity-5) and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/i-is-what-is-not-real).

Maths puzzles (which have the [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) tag) are very often solvable with no extra information (but with plenty of maths knowledge), see for instance [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15412/99-bags-of-apples-and-oranges) and [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16514/mathematical-rebus-ii).

And that's only puzzles with the three top tags!

Also, **[hints should be supplementary](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5008/5373)**: it should always be *possible* (even if hard) to solve the puzzle without looking at spoilertagged hints. So it's definitely OK to post a puzzle without hints at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a rather broad question, but yes, such puzzles exist. We have a tag for it: [enigmatic-puzzles](/questions/tagged/enigmatic-puzzles)
However, not all puzzles tagged like this will fulfil your requirement exactly.

I think the key-question is not necessarily if somebody can *solve* a puzzle without hints, but if it is *clear what the goal is* without specifying it. Take the following 'puzzle':

> 1 + 1 =

Very easy and you don't need hints. But *only* because you *know* what your task is, and that is because you *pre-knowledge*.  Things like [word-search](/questions/tagged/word-search) are of the same category.

However, if you take this pre-knowledge out, your question becomes more interesting and rather philosophically, because why would anybody be interested in solving *anything* just because seeing it? You don't need any hints to solve a jigsaw puzzle, but again 'putting it together' is only clear because your brain demands a "complete picture". It wouldn't if you're only few weeks old...

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what the OP meant. The question is rather unclear...

Comment: @randal'thor Yes. Nevetheless I liked the question, as it makes one *think* about things. (See my edit.)

Comment: It's interesting how a rather crappy question can spawn an interesting philosophical discussion! :-)